# How do I disable Xcode animations?

Tags: macos, mac, xcode

I hope this is the right place to ask this...

I want to get animations disabled for:

- Hide/Show toolbar
- Hide/Show tab bar
- Activate Console :  <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>
- Show Debug Area : <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>y</kbd>
- Show/Hide navigator: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>
- Show/Hide utilities : <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>

I just want to quickly do things :)
Is is possible to disable or at least fasten animations for the given cases ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that someone else has put together a collection of tiny plugins for XCode that disable these animations, along with lots of "fancy" things that you might be interested in removing/disabling.

You can find the project [here](http://github.com/davekeck/Xcode-4-Fixins), with detailed information about the plugins and the installation process [here](http://github.com/davekeck/Xcode-4-Fixins/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: **XCFixin_DisableAnimations** worked like a charm! All the things people has to do because of the sluggish Xcode :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: anyone have an updated answer?

Comment: Bump. The code folding animation is the worst one, it takes forever.